# Python multithreading "ping"

Tags: python, multithreading

I have been trying to make a python script that will ask you for a IP and have many simultaneous PING i shall do.

But it seems like i can only run one PING at a time

I'm running on OSX

```
import _thread
import os
import time

def main():

    threadnbr = 0

    ip = str(input("Input the ip adresse to play with? "))
    threads = int(input("Have many threads? "))

    check(ip)

    if check(ip) == 0:
        print("It is up")
    else:
        print("Is is down")

    thread(ip, threads, threadnbr)

def thread(ip, threads, threadnbr):

    while threads > threadnbr:

        _thread.start_new_thread(dos(ip))

        threadnbr = threadnbr + 1

    else:
        print(threadnbr, " started")

def check(ip):

    response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + ip)

    return response

def dos(ip):

    os.system("ping -i 0.1 -s 8000 " + ip)
    print("1")

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_thread.start_new_thread(dos(ip))
```

You are not providing the arguments correctly here - your code is running in the main thread. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html#thread.start_new_thread) for more details.

Also, you should be using `threading` instead of `thread`. That module is deprecated.

If `dos` means `DoS`, I sincerely hope you're doing this for educational purposes against your own infrastructure.

Comment: I study IT-Technology, and we have about ICMP, so yes it is for education purposes.
But have should i write the program then ?

Comment: @JesperPetersen you *probably* wanted to write `_thread.start_new_thread(dos,(ip,))`

Comment: Have do i stop it again?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Scapy` lib instead of using the builtin ping.
Here is a multithreaded ping with it:

```
import threading
from scapy.all import *

def send_pkt(dst,padding=0):
    pkt       = IP(dst=dst)/ICMP()/Padding('\x00'*padding)
    ans,unans = sr(pkt)
    ans.summary(lambda (s,r): r.sprintf("%IP.src% is alive"))


def thread(dst, threads, threadnbr):

    while threads > threadnbr:
        t = threading.Thread(None, send_pkt, None, (dst,), {'padding':8000})
        t.start()
        threadnbr = threadnbr + 1
    else:
        print(threadnbr, " started")


def main():
    dst       = raw_input("Input the ip adresse to play with? ")
    threads   = int(raw_input("Have many threads? "))
    threadnbr = 0

    send_pkt(dst)

    thread(dst, threads, threadnbr)

main()
```